# Emacs: global key rebinding unless the key has a special meaning

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I would like to globally change the usual binding of a key in Emacs. For instance, <kbd>Return</kbd> runs the command `newline` by default, and I would like it to run `electric-newline-and-maybe-indent` instead. I currently execute

```
(local-set-key [return] 'electric-newline-and-maybe-indent)
```

via a `find-file-hooks` function. Unfortunately this breaks some modes, such as `po-mode`, where <kbd>Return</kbd> has a special meaning. I would like to know some clean way to do the rebinding so that such special meanings are not affected. In particular, I don't want to list specific modes, because I may not know them in advance.

I think that on this example, doing the rebinding only when the initial command bound to <kbd>Return</kbd> is `newline` could be a solution. But how to do this? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you try `global-set-key`?

Comment: @artscan Yes, but `global-set-key` doesn't work as expected (e.g. with `po-mode`). See my comment to abo-abo's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
(global-set-key [return] 'electric-newline-and-maybe-indent)
```

All minor modes that want to override <kbd>RET</kbd>, can still do it.

### update

OK, I think I see the problem here:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'electric-newline-and-maybe-indent)
```

Not sure that `[return]` does, since I always use `kbd`. Just don't use `[return]`.

Comment: Of course, I had tried this, but it overrides the `po-mode` special meaning, for instance, which I don't want.

Comment: Is `po-mode` a minor mode?

Comment: No, it is a major mode (FYI, `po-mode.el` is provided with gettext).

Comment: OK, using `(kbd "RET")` instead of `[return]` solves the problem. I had been using things like `[return]` since the the end of the 1990s at least, and I suppose that `kbd` is more recent. Searching for "global-set-key return" on Google still shows references to it.

Comment: `(global-set-key [return])` is quite strong, it will even override RET in the minibuffer. I don't think anyone wants that.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution, which seems to work in all the cases I've mentioned (without affecting `po-mode`):

```
(substitute-key-definition 'newline 'electric-newline-and-maybe-indent global-map)
```

I found it by reading the `subr.el` file.

However, according to the documentation, this may have unwanted side effects if different keys are bound to `newline`, because all the keys will be affected by the rebind. Otherwise some bindings may be overridden later.